# Failed to find: io.realm:realm-android:0.71.0

Tags: android-studio, realm

Since yesterday, I got Failed to find: io.realm:realm-android:0.71.0.

It is in my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
...
   compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.71.0'
...
}
```

Is this a bug?

The project compiled perfectly before.
What has changed since then:

- Added Crashlytics
- Bumped buildtoolsversion:     buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

Log:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_paidDebugCompile'.
>   Could not find io.realm:realm-android:0.73.1.
>    Searched in the following locations:
>        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/realm/realm-android/0.73.1/realm-android-0.73.1.pom
>        https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/realm/realm-android/0.73.1/realm-android-0.73.1.jar
>        file:/C:/Users/thomasbeerten/.m2/repository/io/realm/realm-android/0.73.1/realm-android-0.73.1.pom
>        file:/C:/Users/thomasbeerten/.m2/repository/io/realm/realm-android/0.73.1/realm-android-0.73.1.jar
>        http://download.crashlytics.com/maven/io/realm/realm-android/0.73.1/realm-android-0.73.1.pom
>        http://download.crashlytics.com/maven/io/realm/realm-android/0.73.1/realm-android-0.73.1.jar
>        file:/C:/Users/thomasbeerten/sdk backup/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/io/realm/realm-android/0.73.1/realm-and
>   roid-0.73.1.pom
>        file:/C:/Users/thomasbeerten/sdk backup/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/io/realm/realm-android/0.73.1/realm-and
>   roid-0.73.1.jar
>        file:/C:/Users/thomasbeerten/sdk backup/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/io/realm/realm-android/0.73.1/realm-andr
>   oid-0.73.1.pom
>        file:/C:/Users/thomasbeerten/sdk backup/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/io/realm/realm-android/0.73.1/realm-andr
>   oid-0.73.1.jar
>    Required by:
>        YoMommaOClock:app:unspecified

Comment: It looks like it stil doesn't use jcenter as maven repository. You can see it goes to mavenCentral and your local maven repo but not jcenter. Can you post your entire build.gradle?

Comment: Also beware, there is a difference between the repository definition inside the buildscript block (which is used for compiling etc.) and outside (which is used at runtime)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Christian from Realm here. Thats odd, neither of these two things should have any effect on Realm.

Without further information i would check:

1) Do you have the following in your build.gradle file?

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

2) Try running "./gradlew clean assemble --refresh-dependencies" from your project. That should refresh your local dependency cache.

Apart from that, we just released 0.73.1, I would suggest you upgrade to that version :)

Comment: I didn't have jcenter() in place! Thanks for the quick answer! (And I updated to 0.73.1) Keep up the good work!

Comment: running "./gradlew clean assemble --refresh-dependencies" worked for me when trying to to upgrade form 0.72 to 0.80

Answer (score 0):

This question already has an accepted answer but in case you still having problems like me, this is what worked for me  i unchecked offline work at

**settings -> build... -> build tools -> build->gradle**

but before make sure you have jcenter() in your dependency as described in the accepted answer.